# NSURLRequest throwing runtime error

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios4, nsurlrequest

Trying to create a request only to have a runtime error thrown. Method initiating the request:

```
- (void)loadMemberData {

    //build URL
    NSMutableString *url = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:appDelegate.apiURL];
    [url appendFormat:@"&subaction=singlestat&memberID=%d", [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"memberID"]];

    NSURL *tempURL = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:url];
    NSLog(@"URL: %@", tempURL);

    //Create conn
    NSURLRequest *request = [[NSURLRequest alloc] requestWithURL:tempURL];
    NSLog(@"%@", request);
    //conn = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
    //[request release];

}
```

The URL logs correctly. I have even checked the object type to make sure everything is correct, and all seems good. No compile time errors or warnings. Stack Trace & Log:

```
[Session started at 2011-03-09 15:02:32 -0500.]
2011-03-09 15:02:33.807 NTR Beer Club[17702:207] URL: https://mydomain.com/path/to/file.php?action=get_app_data&subaction=singlestat&memberID=117
2011-03-09 15:02:33.809 NTR Beer Club[17702:207] -[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x4b02cf0
2011-03-09 15:02:33.811 NTR Beer Club[17702:207] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x4b02cf0'
*** Call stack at first throw:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00db7be9 __exceptionPreprocess + 185
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00f0c5c2 objc_exception_throw + 47
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00db96fb -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 187
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x00d29366 ___forwarding___ + 966
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x00d28f22 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 50
    5   NTR Beer Club                       0x00002190 -[MyStats loadMemberData] + 358
    6   NTR Beer Club                       0x000022c8 -[MyStats viewDidLoad] + 215
    7   UIKit                               0x004b64f0 -[UINib instantiateWithOwner:options:] + 1556
    8   UIKit                               0x004b8081 -[NSBundle(UINSBundleAdditions) loadNibNamed:owner:options:] + 168
    9   UIKit                               0x002c2943 -[UIApplication _loadMainNibFile] + 172
    10  UIKit                               0x002c34ca -[UIApplication _runWithURL:payload:launchOrientation:statusBarStyle:statusBarHidden:] + 291
    11  UIKit                               0x002cddb2 -[UIApplication handleEvent:withNewEvent:] + 1533
    12  UIKit                               0x002c6202 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 71
    13  UIKit                               0x002cb732 _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 7576
    14  GraphicsServices                    0x016eda36 PurpleEventCallback + 1550
    15  CoreFoundation                      0x00d99064 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 52
    16  CoreFoundation                      0x00cf96f7 __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 215
    17  CoreFoundation                      0x00cf6983 __CFRunLoopRun + 979
    18  CoreFoundation                      0x00cf6240 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 208
    19  CoreFoundation                      0x00cf6161 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 97
    20  UIKit                               0x002c2fa8 -[UIApplication _run] + 636
    21  UIKit                               0x002cf42e UIApplicationMain + 1160
    22  NTR Beer Club                       0x00001b98 main + 102
    23  NTR Beer Club                       0x00001b29 start + 53
    24  ???                                 0x00000001 0x0 + 1
)
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'NSException'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be doing

```
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:tempURL];
```

The `requestWithURL:` creates `NSURLRequest` objects that are `autorelease`-d.

The actual error message says "unrecognized selector" because `requestWithURL:` is a class method, but you are using it like an instance method.

Comment: Ahhh. This is the most confusing part about learning Objective-C. Memory. When to allocate. When to release. When to init. When to set to nil. I'm not getting it.

Comment: @Chris Rules of thumb: `init` only after an `alloc`; creation methods that do not start with the word "new" or "create" return `autorelease`-d objects; when you `alloc` you must pair it with a call to `release` or `autorelease` somewhere in your code